# Allow an array of hashes with a dynamic hash (hstore) inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, hstore, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm stuck with strong_parameters and this array of hashes with a dynamic hash (hstore) inside.

The structure is the following:

```
{ contact_sources: [
  { id: 1, filled_fields: { randomstuff: 'randomdata', dunno: 123 } },
  { id: 2, filled_fields: { blah: 'blabla', dunno: 9043 } }
] }
```

So, my main attempt is the following:

```
params.permit(contact_sources: [{:filled_fields => []}, 'id'])
```

Which doesn't return filled_fields. Any suggestion on how to deal with it?

**Update 1:**
I have the following model:

```
class ContactSource < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Fields: id:integer, filled_fields:hstore
end
```

In my action, I'm submitting **multiple records** at once (mass update), so I have an array of contact_source, but actually they don't belong to anything, it's just a mass update.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding how this is set up... but perhaps you could use an attr_accessor to refer to the contact_sources hash and then permit the attr_accessor?

Comment: @user3334690: No, I don't have any association, see my update 1 it should explain better what I'm doing

Comment: what does the form look like?

Comment: No form @user3334690 , I perform an ajax request and I pass that array

Comment: oh I think I see what you're doing now... I think what you're looking for is merge (and maybe deep_merge given your hash) instead of permit... I'm not that familiar with strong parameters yet, though, so I'm not exactly sure how to use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible to do it with "plain" strong_parameters syntax. The only option you have is to actually, **after filtering**, re-add those values with a loop. I know it's terrible but it's the only way right now. I submitted a bug to Rails actually.